# What's wrong with my code. Deleting repeated letters in given string

Tags: python, string, loops

I am getting out of range in terminal. In my opinion  i wrote correctly. Please help me to find whats wrong.

Result should be string without repeated letters.

```
str1 = "asssalomu aleykum bootcamp foundation n28"
length = len(str1)
i = 0
while i < length:
    if str1[i] != " ":
        str1 = str1[:i+1] + str1[i+1:].replace(str1[i], "")
    i+=1
print(str1)
```

Comment: you could do the same but start by the end of the string so that str1[i] still exists when you remove characters

Comment: Your `str1` gets shorter since you are removing letters, but `i` won't stop increasing until it hits the original string length. This causes it to access an index past the length of your shortened `str1`. Also, do you mean to replace any repetition of a previous letter or just a sequence of repeated letters like `sss`?

Answer (score -1):

Using `re`:

```
result = re.sub(r"(.)\1+", r"\1", str1)
```

Using `itertools.groupby`

```
result = ''.join([c for c, _ in groupby(str1)])
```

Without any imports:

```
result = ''.join([c for c, n in zip(str1, str1[1:] + " ") if c != n])
```

I'm using zip here to have a reference to the current character `c` and the next character `n`. This is functionally equivilent to:

```
char_list = []
for c, n in zip(str1, str1[1:] + " "):
    if c != n:
        char_list.append(c)
result = ''.join(char_list)
```

Result for all approaches:

```
asalomu aleykum botcamp foundation n28
```

Comment: Why u put -1 Jab?

Comment: What did you expect? You don't even attempt to answer the question. (Plus your code does something different.)

Comment: Thats right Kelly but why downvote me here Jab?

Comment: Ok then Sorry Jab.

Comment: But your answer is not what i searched

Comment: So you want no repeated characters at all? Or only if a character is followed by the same character?